# Exceptions - should I prefer a logging library over java.util.logging?

Tags: java, logging, exception, coding-style

Fact is most people beginning java programming just leave exception handling for later. As the `e.printStackTrace();` littering my code have annoyed me for too long now and having read the very informative article [here](http://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns) I realized that the Right Thing is apparently to rethrow the exceptions and log in the highest possible level (at least for checked exceptions - which is the thing I care for at the moment). So I have to look at loggers (which is a whole subject I guess, meaning should I create them per class, per method, should I wrap them etc) but first things first : should I go for some specialized lib (like apache's log4j) or even better for a wrapper (like SLF4J) or stay with java.util.logging ? What are you people using and why ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "rethrow"? Checked exceptions should be *wrapped* into unchecked exceptions, which are then thrown.

Comment: As for logging, SLF4J+Logback would be the top choice these days. This is especially important when you use some libraries that have their own logging, usually against Apache Commons Logging or Log4j. With SLF4J you'll be able to most elegantly make all those APIs converge into a single logging back-end.

Comment: @Marko : concerning rethrow practices - yes actually what I mean is rethrow wrapped in some exception I created - see the article cited. I am mostly interested in the loggers part of the matter though in this question

Comment: For future reference, it is not acceptable practice to post links that you expect every single potential answerer to click through and page through. Post the relevant points into your question. Another good practice would be not to go on for three sentences about topics that are **not** your question. This is not your personal blogging space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my (an many other's) opinion, you should absolutely use a third-party logging solution - java.util.logging has lots of 'issues'. Log4J is handy, and widely-used, but SLF4J is better. Better yet, [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) is an SLF4J implementation that was written by the same person who wrote Log4J, so it's the current recommended solution for those who would otherwise use Log4J.